# Play (2.4) routes outside controllers

Tags: scala, playframework

How to construct reverse routes in (Scala) Play 2.4 outside controllers? If I import `controllers._` and try to use routes, I get a compilation error:

> Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here

```
package models 

import org.joda.time._ 
import play.api.libs.json._ 

case class Attendee (id: Long, status: Boolean, ... , pictureUrl: Option[String], ...) 

object Attendee { implicit val attendeeWrites = new Writes[Attendee] { 

def writes(att: Attendee) = Json.obj( "id" -> att.id, "picture" -> att.pictureUrl.map 
    { somePictureUrl => routes.PrivateWS.getAttendeeImage(att.eventId, att.id)
    .absoluteURL() })
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Can you share a small example?

Comment: It cant find an implicit RequestHeader. Have you done the relevant 'imports' and 'extend's?

Comment: Based on "standard" directory layout of basic play applications, I have controllers and models packages in app directory. One of model members looks like: package models

import org.joda.time._
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Attendee (id: Long, status: Boolean, ... , pictureUrl: Option[String], ...)

object Attendee {
  implicit val attendeeWrites = new Writes[Attendee] {
    def writes(att: Attendee) = Json.obj(
      "id"              -> att.id,
      "picture"         -> att.pictureUrl.map { somePictureUrl => routes.PrivateWS.getAttendeeImage(att.eventId, att.id).absoluteURL() })

Comment: The problem exactly is that I don't know what to import or extend

Comment: `import play.api.mvc.Request`, and:    \n                                                      `def writes(att: Attendee)(implicit request: Request[_]) = Json.obj( "id"...`

Comment: Thank you Robert, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Robert, thanks for the edit. However, after applying suggested modifications (and importing controllers.routes) I'm getting compilation error (which does not occur if I omit routes completely) on line implicit val attendeeWrites ...):  `object creation impossible, since method writes in trait Writes of type (o: models.Attendee)play.api.libs.json.JsValue is not defined
[error] (Note that A does not match models.Attendee)
[error]   implicit val attendeeWrites = new Writes[Attendee] {
[error]                                     ^
[error] one error found`

Comment: Was this the error you got before adding `implicit request`? If not, then you probably have a different issue now with `attendeeWrites`

Comment: Not sure if you've had a look at [these](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Writes) but you might find some inspiration to fix the new error.

Comment: Everything worked fine before adding the implicit request. I googled around (including the link you mentioned), but I couldn't find the answer on how does the implicit request interfere with the, otherwise healthy, code.

Answer (score 0):

I have create an helper and use controllers.route.etc etc and works well,

in your case you can try

```
controllers.routes.PrivateWS.getAttendeeImage(att.eventId, att.id).absoluteURL()
```